# Rosjava: How to generate new services

Tags: ros, service, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am using rosjava to set up a service. For testing I have set up a package with roscreate-pkg. (GetCylinders.srv) The service was generated and the package was build with rosmake. All cpp files are generated.

```
#no request
---
string name
float32 likelihood
```

I have already set the dependency in the rosjava service (i.e. reasoner_msgs). Here is the manifest file I use for the service.

```
<depend package="rosjava" />
<depend package="std_msgs" />
<depend package="reasoner_msgs" />
```

How do I proceed further? How can I tell rosjava to generate the corresponding java service? Is there a step by step manual somewhere?

Cheers,

Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27504/rosjava:-how-to-generate-new-services/) by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2012-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Stupid me. I forgot to call rosmake again after setting the dependency. Now I included the generated java file. with #import org.ros.service.reasoner_msgs.*;

---

Originally posted by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) with karma: 202 on 2012-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0